# need netezza to snowflake serialization equivalent query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, netezza

I have following command in netezza and looking for equivalent in snowflake. Any idea ?

```
SET serializable = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct equivalent to this in Snowflake.  You should read through the transactions and locking in the documentation to better understand your options.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/transactions.html